# stop values going into negative after zero in react

Tags: reactjs

counter is a component in which i placed a decrement button in its I want that if the value is zero it will stop going to negative values I have set `this.setState(oldState => ( {counters:( oldState.counters > 0) ? (oldState.counters - 1) : 0 } ))`but it is not working its giving error by using call back function its working fine few hours ago but it giving error
[image]

here is my code

```
class Counters extends Component {
    state={
        counters:[
            {id:1, value:0},
            {id:2, value:0},
            {id:3, value:0},
            {id:4, value:0}
        ],
       

    }
    handleIncrement=counter=>{
        const counters =[...this.state.counters];
        const index = counters.indexOf(counter);
        counters[index]={...counter}
        counters[index].value++;
        this.setState({counters})
    }
    handleDecrement=counter=>{
        const counters =[...this.state.counters];
        const index = counters.indexOf(counter);
        counters[index]={...counter}
        counters[index].value--;
        this.setState(oldState => (
            {counters:( oldState.counters > 0) ? (oldState.counters - 1) : 0 }
        ))
    }
    handleDelete=(counterid)=>{
      const counters = this.state.counters.filter(m=>m.id !== counterid)
      this.setState({counters})
    }
    handleReset=()=>{
        const counters = this.state.counters.map(m=>{ 
            m.value = 0;
             return m
        })
        this.setState({counters})

    }
    
    render() {
        
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>{this.state.counters.reduce((a,b)=>({value:a.value+b.value})).value}</h1>
                <button onClick={this.handleReset} className="btn btn-secondary btn-sm">RESET</button>
           {this.state.counters.map(m=>
           <Counter key={m.id} 
             id={m.id} getDelete={this.handleDelete}
              onIncrement={this.handleIncrement}
              onDecrement={this.handleDecrement}
              counter={m}
              >
           
              
           </Counter>) }


            </div>

        );
    }
}
```

Comment: You are setting the `counters` property to `0`, but `counters` should be an array.

Comment: how to fix it i was trying no luck

Comment: <Counter> isn't defined - how do you expect anyone to fix your code without enough of an example to work from?

Answer (score 0):

Untested, but I think this is what you are after:

```
handleDecrement=counter=>{
    this.setState( oldState => {
       const counters = oldState.counters;
       const index = counters.indexOf(counter);
       
       counters[index]={...counter}
       if (counters[index].value > 0) counters[index].value--;
       return { counters };
    }
 }
```

Although some of that isn't really sensible, I think this can be shortened further:

```
handleDecrement=counter=>{
    this.setState( oldState => {
       const counters = oldState.counters;
       if (counter.value > 0) counter.value--;
       return { counters };
    }
 }
```